# [sql]Database design: preset values

Tags: sql, database-design

Let's say we have an ice cream application. 
For all ice cream shops, the admin of all shops will define a list of preset icecream options (for example, shop1 will have the vanilla icecream which costs 1$ and chocolate icecream which costs 3$). For each shop, its manager can change this list: modify the price, modify the flavor. At any point the admin can come and change the preset icecream options. In this case, the shop manager should be able to see and accept the changes if he wants. So for the shops, we need a reference to the preset.

Solution1: I thought of having a table that holds the data defined by admin and another one for the shop (the values that were modified by the manager). The advantage here is that the presets are separated by the actual data. The disadvantage is that the data is duplicated.

```
Icecream_preset (id, flavour, price)
Icecream_shop (id, IcecreamPresetId, ShopId, flavour, price)
```

Solution2: Have an icecream table that holds all the values, a table which holds a reference to the icecream for the preset and a table that is customized by the shop manager, which holds a reference to the preset and a reference to the modified icecream. The disavantage here is that the icecream table will contain both preset and modified data.

```
Icecream (id, flavour, price)
Icecream_preset(id, IcecreamId)
Icecream_shop(id, Icecream_presetId, IcecreamId)
```

Which is the best solution or is there a better solution?